# How to create index for a query uses the document id cloud firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this query in my android app :

```
        fireStoreQuestions.document(subject).collection(subject)
            .whereEqualTo("reviewed", true)
            .whereGreaterThan(FieldPath.documentId(), randomId)
            .limit(1)
            .get()
```

I want to know how to add an index to this query in cloud firestore. I don't know how to represent the document id in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) or if you are using Android Studio, you'll find in your logcat a message that sounds like this:

> W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(subject where reviewed == true and id > randomId) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/...

So you can simply click on that link or copy and paste the url into a web broswer and you index will be created automatically.

Comment: I have a similar query that also uses the document id and would like to construct the query manually via the Firebase Console. How do I add the document id to the index. Specifically, the "Create a composite index" wizard asks for a "Field path" value.

Comment: @cjmconie That's a question that cannot be simply answered in a comment, so I suggest you post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Yes agreed. I created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/q/63019155/3589408 – which has now been answered.