# Firestore query with where(in:) and where(isEqual:)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is the following composite `where(in:)` and `where(isEqualTo:)` query possible in Firebase Firestore?

(Swift)

```swift
let taskDocIds = ["0ArJnMgTfDkvolUcZR8E", "0cdcZsfaEJQpsiByJIgH"]

return db.collection("tasks")
      .whereField("status", isEqualTo: "approved")
      .whereField(Firebase.FieldPath.documentID(), in: taskDocIds)
      .limit(to: 100)
      .getDocuments(as: TaskModel.self)
```

My security rules enforce that only tasks with `status` as `approved` may be read. However the the query above results in an error (see below) when the `status` of any of the tasks whose id is in the `taskDocIds` array has a `status` other than `approved`.

> Error: Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions."

If the query is possible, does a composite index need to be created? And if so, how does one go about configuring that manually (using Firebase Console) for a FieldPath document id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission errors can never be resolved by adding an index.

The problem is that the rule doesn't know if your entire set of `taskDocIds` would be allowed without checking them all individually.  [Firebase security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters), so, when performing a query, the rule **will not read and check each document individually** and give you only the ones that match.  Without assurance that every document that *could* match the query absolutely *does* match the query, it simply fails the entire rule.

Your alternative is to simply `getDocument()` each one individually.  With individual document gets, the rule **will** check the individual fields of the document.

Comment: I thought multiple whereField clauses in a query are treated as a logical AND? So the query would already guarantee that the 'status' is 'approved' (by: `.whereField("status", isEqualTo: "approved"`) and so Security Rules should be happy?

Comment: That's not the way it works.  The rules don't know if the requested document IDs also have stats=approved.  It would have to read each document to know for sure, and it won't do that.  Your query would be allowed if the rules specifically checked for those strings in the document ID.